# why this coequalizer is $S^2$

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory

In Basic category theory(Tom Leinster) page 133, the author says this coequalizer is $S^2$,
[image]

Here $D$ is open unit disk, "+" is disjoint union and figure 5.2 b is
[image]
why this coequalizer is $S^2$, the author does not explain it, do we some theorem to prove it ?

Comment: Coequalizers is $\mathsf{Top}$ correspond to "gluing" parts of your space together. Here your space is $D+D$ and you're gluing the two $D$s together along the cylinder $S^1 \times (0,1)$. In the attached photo you can see the cylinders are the overlapping portions of the two disks, and if we glue them together we get exactly a sphere (again, as the picture shows).

Comment: Here is a nice exercise: let $U, V$ be open subspaces of a topological space $X$ such that $U \cup V = X$. Then $X$ is the coequalizer of the two inclusion maps $U \cap V \rightrightarrows U \sqcup V$. in other words $X$ is obtained by gluing $U$ and $V$ along their common intersection.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor yes, intuitively I can understand, but is there a formal proof?

Comment: Like many details in algebraic topology, the formal proof is annoying. There's a relatively easy proof in terms of [homotopy type theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_type_theory), but classically the proof requires you to actually name all of the functions involved (even though they only matter up to homotopy). It's precisely these annoying details that led me to leave a comment instead of an answer :P

Comment: @HallaSurvivor thank you, is there an example to use HTT to prove a similar question? I  do not find it.

Comment: To make this precise, you can first show that the coequalizer is given by the quotient space obtained from $D+D$ by identifying the points from $S^1\times(0,1)$ in the corresponding copies (this can be done by observing that it satisfies the defining universal property), then it is also not hard to show this quotient is homeomorphic to $S^2$.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor: I don't think homotopy type theory could possibly prove anything like this. It might prove something about the *homotopy* coequalizer, but 1) you'd need to show separately that this has anything to do with the ordinary coequalizer, and 2) you'd only end up with a homotopy type at the end and this is a statement about topological spaces on the nose.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan -- fair point. I was implicitly thinking about the homotopy type of $S^2$. HoTT isn't the right tool for the job after all.